# Custom directive for restuctured text?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I'm trying to use docutils's rst2html.py to convert rst document to html.

A external hyper link created with

```
`How to create Product <Django.url('reservation:manual:product:index')>`_
```

is converted to

```
<a class="reference external" href="Django.url('reservation:manual:product:index')">How to create Product</a>
```

I'd like to modify rst2html.py (or related files) so that I can generate the following instead.

```
<Link
to={Django.url('reservation:manual:product:index')}
>
</Link>
```

I don't need to use the embedded URIs format to express a link.

It seems I can create a custom directive to specify a parsing/generating rule.

But with my short knowledge of RST and its parsers, I'm not sure if I can embed a link for a word phrase in a sentence with directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply write a post-processor. Assuming that Django URLs won't have internal markup or escapable characters like `&` and `"`, a simple regex will do here (despite the general cursedness for tasks even slightly more complex), like:

```
import re
s = ('head <a class="reference external" href="'
     "Django.url('reservation:manual:product:index')"
     '">How to create Product</a> tail')
r = re.sub(r'<a class=".*?" href="(Django[.]url[(].*?[)])">.*?</a>', 
           r'<Link to={\1}></Link>', s)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
head <Link to={Django.url('reservation:manual:product:index')}></Link> tail
```

Comment: ah, great idea. Thanks!